# Twilio SMS A2P 10DLC and Sub accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have been utilizing Twilio within SAAS application to facilitate SMS communication with our customers, specifically for sharing invoice updates from our web users to their customers. However, I've encountered an issue where messages are currently being blocked.

I am considering an alternative approach and wanted to seek the guidance. Would transitioning to a sub-account strategy, as opposed to continuing with the 10DLC approach, be a suitable solution for my situation?

I appreciate your expertise and any insights you can provide to help me make an informed decision. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 10DLC for each phone number whether in a subaccount or a primary account. If you are an ISV, using subaccounts is recommended. The chart on this page shows the various [ISV Types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#identify-your-isv-type) but makes this recommendation:

> ISV architecture #1 You use subaccounts for each customer. You will
> need to collect the required information from customers to fill in the
> business profile and campaign use case registration forms that make up
> US A2P 10DLC onboarding.
>
> Information architecture
>
> Each subaccount contains a secondary business profile associated with
> that customer. Each campaign maps to that secondary business profile
> and a messaging service within that subaccount. Refer to the diagram
> for ISVs using subaccounts.
>
> NOTE: We would recommend this as the preferred architecture for A2P
> 10DLC Brand and Campaign registration. In this architecture, the
> messaging traffic of each end customer is clearly separated from that
> of every other end customer. In a case where one of your customers is
> a bad actor and sends non-compliant messages, Twilio could decide to
> suspend their account. Having each subaccount mapped to an individual
> customer allows you to minimize impact when this happens because the
> noncompliant traffic is isolated. Moreover, separating your customers
> into subaccounts allows much easier analytics tracking of individual
> customers’ messaging activity.

However, from what you described, it not clear if you are an ISV or a Direct Brand. Using this chart to [Determine Your Customer Type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc#determine-your-customer-type) and follow the recommended architecture.

Comment: Yes I fall in ISV "My SaaS Lawn Care web application offers a Paid Registration to users and These users send invoices via sms to their customers." and I was not using the subaccounts earlier. and what I understand is that First I have to register my users to subaccounts and then I have to compliant with US A2P 10DLC.

Comment: just to clarify, First I've to migrate our users to subaccounts and then have to compliant with A2P 10DLC as our parent account is configured with A2P 10DLC.

Comment: You will need to do the same A2P 10DLC process for the parent account and the subaccounts. I am not sure about the "migrate our users" if this is referring to actual user accounts logging into Twilio or you mean updating account sids and auth tokens in your app to use the new subaccount.